# How can I observe API call based on user submit button and at same time getValue from edit text which is necessary for submit action?

Tags: android

The problem is if I'll write observe statement in onCreate, it won't observe based on user click event. Because I want to only call repository API when user fill value in edit text and submit button, then only I can get value which I have to pass in repository to make API call and pass that value to API.

**repository**

```
public MutableLiveData<License> getLicenseData(String licenseKey, String macAddress, int productId) {
        final MutableLiveData<License> licenseData = new MutableLiveData<>();
        apiCall.getLicenseData(licenseKey, macAddress, productId).enqueue(new Callback<License>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<License> call, Response<License> response) {
                licenseData.setValue(response.body());
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<License> call, Throwable t) {
                licenseData.setValue(null);
            }
        });
        return licenseData;
    }
```

**ViewModel class**

```
 private void getLicenseData(String licenseKey, String macAddress, int productId) {
            mutableLiveData = manualLicenseRepository.getLicenseData(licenseKey, macAddress, productId);
        }

public void onClick(View view) {
    switch (view.getId()) {
        case R.id.btn_submit:
            try {
                getLicenseData(key.getValue(), "null", FIXED_PRODUCT_ID);
            } catch (NullPointerException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            break;


    }
}
```

Activity - onCreate:

```
 protected void init() {
        manualLicenseKeyViewModel.init();
        manualLicenseKeyViewModel.getLicenseRepository().observe(this, this);
    }
```

Comment: If you are using `dataBinding` you can easily check if `editText` have any value at the time of `onClick()` and do certain actions, please tell me if you need example

Comment: @RahulGaur the problem is onClick is my own method, and I'm doing in viewmodel class, not activity. after user click in submit button, my onclick will fire inviewmodel class, from that I'll get some edit text value, and call the repository where retrofit callback is there. so in all this, where to put observe in activity?

Answer (score 1):

First I will suggest you to Add [data binding](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/start) in your App

now in your Activity `XML` do something like this

```
<!--here it is 2 way binding-->
<EditText
    ...
    android:text="@={viewmodel.key}
    ... />

<!--here it is single way binding-->
<Button
    ...
    android:onClick="@{() -> viewmodel.doneClicked()}"
    ... />
```

Now in your `ViewModel`

```
//value in key will be same as value in the EditText as it is bidirectional data binding
public MutableLiveData<String> key = new MutableLiveData<>();

//update this MutableLiveData accordingly
private MutableLiveData<Boolean> isDataAvailable = new MutableLiveData<>();

//observe this LiveData
LiveData<Boolean> isDataAvailable(){
    return isDataAvailable;
}

public void doneClicked(){
    //here you can get value of your "key"
    //this method will call when clicking on the button
    //you can call your custom method from here,
    //also update data in "isDataAvailable"
}
```

In your Activity

```
viewModel.isDataAvailable().observe(this, aBoolean -> {
    //here you will receive change in value of isDataAvailable
}
```

**PS** 
Your question is not clear at all, and your code is not helpful

Do you want to observe change in `mutableLiveData` of `getLicenseData(...)` inside your `viewModel`?

> ```
> mutableLiveData = manualLicenseRepository.getLicenseData(licenseKey, macAddress, productId);
> ```

Please also change the name of this variable to something related the data it is getting, mutableLiveData is not a good variable name

**Edit 1**
try this to observe changes in the data, it is recommended to observe `LiveData` but you can observer `MutableLiveData` as you have not provided sufficient information I m using your `mutableLiveData` variable

In your `Activity` try this

```
viewModel.mutableLiveData.observe(this, license -> {
    //here you can observe changes in your mutableLiveData when It receives data from Repo
    //here license is the object of data inserted into mutableLiveData from repo
});
```

Please explain more.

Hope this will help!

Comment: Can you please post code with repository? Also, I want to observe getLicenseData() method, but in that method licenseKey parameter which I need to take input from user. so how can I observe? And I clearly want to observe in Activity only.

Comment: You want data `A` which needs input `B`, and you want to observe `A` in your activity?

Comment: true! I want to observe data which will coming from API. But API call only possible when user submit the button, and user only can submit the button when user input license key in edit text. and I need that license key in API parameter.

Comment: And where are you stuck? I guess you are stuck at observing the data afterwards, you can observe `mutableLiveData` variable in your activity

Comment: onChanged method is not called at all!

Comment: And the problem was, I was observing getLicenseData instead of mutableLiveData. And getLicenseData() was expecting user input! Thanks anyway.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/208750/discussion-between-rahul-gaur-and-pooja-singh).

Comment: I want to observe API call in my main activity when user will click on button with some edit text input

Answer (score 0):

I assume the methods you posted are from your Activity. Merely adding a method named `onClick` doesn't do anything at all; you need to attach a click listener to your button. For example, something like this in your `onCreate` method:

```
findViewById(R.id.btn_submit).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        try {
            getLicenseData(key.getValue(), "null", FIXED_PRODUCT_ID);
        } catch (NullPointerException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Can you show how it is hooked up to your UI? This is not clear from the code you posted. My understanding of your problem is that you want your `onClick` method to be called when a submit button is tapped, but this is not happening. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: Nope, if you know about MVVM with observer design pattern, then you can understand my question. onClick is getting called and also it hit the API, after that Observer overridden method onChanged should be fired with the API response result that is already set.

Comment: solve my question, and I'll give you a green tick mark, if you can\

Comment: I don't understand the question. I'm not saying the question is improper, only that more information (that is, code) is needed.

Comment: sorry Petter, I deleted that comment

Comment: see this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60427788/how-can-i-make-it-live-data-observer-working-based-on-user-click-event-with-take

Comment: It's not clear what is the problem here?! You are not receiving live data events in Activity?

Comment: Can you please help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60464891/how-to-correctly-use-pojo-if-http-logcat-response-is-200-but-it-is-going-to-onf

Answer (score 0):

You have LiveData defined inside the method which is wrong. LiveData is something that's constantly observed by View(Activity) and therefore it needs to be held in ViewModel/Repository in a member variable.

Also, your repository looks redundant (does not do anything). I suggest redefining LiveData as a member variable of your ViewModel, making the request inside the ViewModel and posting the value to LiveData.

If you just need to send request and receive result then you don't need to even use LiveData, just use some Listener/Callback interface instead.

Comment: So many things may come in future. Also I want to exactly follow MVVM. Also your suggestion is correct as of now, but still I want to learn that how this things can be done, for that please post your answer with code, and explain me what's wrong am I doing?

Comment: Having repository does not make your architecture more or less MVVMish. It's just an extension which can be used for mapping/caching/abstracting data source/simpler callbacks etc. You dont use that. Therefore as a start, you can ditch the repository for now and implement it later when you understand more about the architecture.

The core of MVVM is View observing a Model and reacting to it. 
Just define your liveData as a member variable inside ViewModel. Just like it is done in all the basic tutorials like this one: 
https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/livedata

Comment: Anyhow, I'll change it. But if I'll skip the problems like this, then how can I learn? Atleast give me the complete answer.

Comment: I suggest you make it work without repository first. It's easier to learn MVVM when you have plain MVVM without extra stuff. Then you can add repository later.

Comment: I respect your suggestion, but I why don't you're teaching me with repository?

Comment: Can you please help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60464891/how-to-correctly-use-pojo-if-http-logcat-response-is-200-but-it-is-going-to-onf